# unobtrusive feedback when the page is loaded (onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-feedback

I added this script in the footer of my page that will flash the usually black background of the page once the page is loaded:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        function highlight_background(){
            if(document.getElementById('content')) {
                //fading background:
                $('#content').css({backgroundColor:"#081108"});
                $('#content').animate({backgroundColor: "black"}, 2000);
            }
         }
         highlight_background();
)}
</script>
```

This looks great on black background like in my [space online game](http://www.spacetrace.org).

But now I am planning to implement a feedback for the user in a serious application of a customer of mine that has white background. there it looks too playful.

Any idea how to manage **an unobstrusive feedback** once the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

flash a pink screen instead:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function highlight_background(){
        if(document.getElementById('content')) {
            //fading background:
            $('#content').css({backgroundColor:"#081108"});
            $('#content').animate({backgroundColor: "pink"}, 2000);
        }
     }
     highlight_background();
)}
</script>
```